# Why do HTML and BODY elements overlap?

Tags: html, css

With this simple HTML/CSS template below, I expected BODY to be contained within HTML element. Why is it not? I separated the css for HTML and BODY to give different colors.

https://jsfiddle.net/jwinnd/w95ngLqc/3/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>

  <style>
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: solid 30px red;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: solid 30px blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! If sometimes you see a web developer pulling his hair or gnashing his teeth, he is probably messing up with this problem. You may think that when you determine the height of a block-level element it includes the content box to the outer side of the border. **But it is not!** When you set the height of an element you only set its content's size, and not the borders and paddings. It is really common for developers to set all element to have `box-sizing` of `border-box`. You can do this by adding this peace of code to the top of your css style. :

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So, here is your code result after adding this property. Also, note that the body element has a default margin. Be sure to disable that too:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>

  <style>
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: solid 30px red;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin:0;
      border: solid 30px blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you actually stated something that wasn't in all of the other answers here?

Comment: @Martin Yeah! Setting all the elements to be border-box by `*` selector! It is better to do this rather than repeating in body and html elements. I have seen this technique in a lot of sites.

Comment: Yes, that useful nugget is a single sentence. It would also help if you used the correct syntax on your example `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want. Don't overthink it. The `box-sizing` property is the most important in this scenario. The `box-sizing` will measure the element's `width` and `height` with the `border` included.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>demo</title>
    
        <style>
            html {
                border: solid 30px red;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100%; 
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%; 
            }
            body {
                border: solid 30px blue;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100%; 
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%; 
            }

        </style>
    </head>     
    <body>
        <script>

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: position is irrelevant here. But you're correct re box-sizing

Answer (score 2):

## Your Question:

In short; you're asking why the body element is not directly on top of the html parent as you would expect.

## Explanation:

The fact is, **IT IS**, but the way that the CSS is set out, is that some CSS rules and some default styling factors offset this direct layering.

In this case, the HTML and the body 'boxes' are only by default measured by the system in terms of it's "content area" rather than it's whole "margin" + "border" + "content" area.

[Read about CSS `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

You have a border on both, so the child element is offset against the border, but the child element has also been told to be `100% width`, so it *must* overflow the parent because the true total size of the child element is  "border" (30px x 2) + "padding" (0px) + "content" (100%)

As well as this, the `<body>` element has a default margin value of 8px (0.5rem standard font size) on all edges so this as well is not accounted for by the sizing system because the margin (like the border) is not in the "content area" and so causes a *further* offset.

However, the child element is forced to being 100% of its parent so it has to "overflow" at the far end of the parent (`<html>`) box; causing your borders to overlap.

From the above you can see your `body` element actually has a *TOTAL* width of:

> margin: 16px
> border: 60px
> content: 100%

So the body is 100% + 76px of the parent element's size.

CSS can't not show any part of the display, so it is forced to overflow the parent to keep everything viewable (You can change this with: `overflow:hidden;`)

---

Further to the above, the `<body>` element overflows the parent `<html>` element because the parent has been set to a width of 100% as well, so it will be the maximum width of the child (`body`) "content area" rather than the area it actually effects on the screen. This is why the border on the bottom right of your example has blue outside the red; because the system thinks:

> This container [the screen size] has a width of X so I need to be X wide for my contents and then I can add my border and my margin

the child element meanwhile processes:

> I must take up all the width of my parent, plus my border and plus my margin that I have.

---

Be default `<body>` has a natural margin on it, and the border itself set on `<html>` will force its child elements to be within the border rather than on top of the border.

My fixes to remove default settings and browser inherited styles, and force the box model to respect all areas of the box not just the contents.

## Tweaked Version of your HTML:

```css
html {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border: solid 30px red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0; /* Added to body */
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border: solid 30px blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    /* often added to the *{ .. } element to apply to all elements on a page */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>demo 2</title>
    
        <style>


        </style>
    </head>     
    <body>
 Hello 2
    </body>
</html>
```

## CSS Changes made:

- Removed default margin on the `body` element.
- Changed `box-sizing` to border box whereby the DOM Box model is set to the border rather than simply the box contents.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>

  <style>
    html {
    box-sizing:border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: solid 30px red;
    }
    
    body {
    margin:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: solid 30px blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SnackOverflow. Code only answers are rarely very useful and give no details as to *why* a solution works, please consider revising your answer and **edit**ing.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Some great explanations in here!

Comment: you can search about this problem in internet .